# Not able to store information into Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Using firestore this for login and register user with email name , and password.

I'm writing a code to login and Register with user email and password. And I'm trying to store that data into firestore and firebase storage.

I'm storing the registered person's image in to Firebase Storage. And other detailed information into firestore like name,email etc. Now the image is going to firebaseStorage but the other information that should be stored in firestore, is not going in firestore.

[The registred user is being authenticated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXxGt.png)

[Profile Images are getting uploaded successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5PBd.png)

[But the Firestore is Empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNd7L.png)

**Register.jsx** file

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Add from "../img/addAvatar.png";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth, db, storage } from "../firebase";
import { ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { useNavigate, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Register = () => {
  const [err, setErr] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    setLoading(true);
    e.preventDefault();
    const displayName = e.target[0].value;
    const email = e.target[1].value;
    const password = e.target[2].value;
    const file = e.target[3].files[0];

    try {
      //Create user
      const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);

      //Create a unique image name
      const date = new Date().getTime();
      const storageRef = ref(storage, `${displayName + date}`);

      await uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file).then(() => {
        getDownloadURL(storageRef).then(async (downloadURL) => {
          try {
            //Update profile
            await updateProfile(res.user, {
              displayName,
              photoURL: downloadURL,
            });
            //create user on firestore
            await setDoc(doc(db, "users", res.user.uid), {
              uid: res.user.uid,
              displayName,
              email,
              photoURL: downloadURL,
            });

            //create empty user chats on firestore
            await setDoc(doc(db, "userChats", res.user.uid), {});
            navigate("/");
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            setErr(true);
            setLoading(false);
          }
        });
      });
    } catch (err) {
      setErr(true);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="formContainer">
      <div className="formWrapper">
        <span className="logo">Lama Chat</span>
        <span className="title">Register</span>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input required type="text" placeholder="display name" />
          <input required type="email" placeholder="email" />
          <input required type="password" placeholder="password" />
          <input required style={{ display: "none" }} type="file" id="file" />
          <label htmlFor="file">
            <img src={Add} alt="" />
            <span>Add an avatar</span>
          </label>
          <button disabled={loading}>Sign up</button>
          {loading && "Uploading and compressing the image please wait..."}
          {err && <span>Something went wrong</span>}
        </form>
        <p>
          You do have an account? <Link to="/register">Login</Link>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

While registering new a user, its showing something went wrong.
The information is being authenticated and images are successfully getting uploaded succcessfully, but Firestore is empty

[image]

Comment: Did you see in console once you hit register. There might be insufficient rule permission to write in firestrore. Did you check that?

Comment: You'll also want to check the value of `err`, as that likely contains more information about what went wrong.